# Coefficients of a certain Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, laurent-series

If $$e^{t(z - 1/z)/2} = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} J_n(t)z^n$$

is the Laurent expansion in $\mathbb{C}^*$, how can I show that

$$ J_{-n}(t) = (-1)^n J_n(t)$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$e^{t(z-z^{-1})/2}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}J_n(t)z^n \tag 1$$

Now, enforce the substitution $z\to -z^{-1}$ followed by $n\to -n$.

---

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution.

> Starting from $(1)$, we enforce the substitution $z\to -1/z$ to obtain $$\begin{align}e^{t(-z^{-1}+z)/2}&=e^{t(z-z^{-1})/2}\\\\&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}J_n(t)(-1)^n z^{-n}\tag 2\end{align}$$Then, in $(2)$, transforming the summation index by letting $n\to -n$ reveals $$e^{t(z-z^{-1})/2}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n\,J_{-n}(t)\,z^n \tag 3$$Comparing $(1)$ and $(3)$ and exploiting the uniqueness of the Laurent expansion, yields the coveted relationship $$J_n(t)=(-1)^nJ_{-n}(t)$$

Comment: You have $\displaystyle e^{(z-z^{-1})/2}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}J_n(t)z^n$ where you need $\displaystyle e^{t(z-z^{-1})/2}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}J_n(t)z^n$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Michael, thank you for the nice catch!  I've edited accordingly.  +1 -Mark